# How to Exclude a file from a dependacy in Grails 2.2.2

Tags: selenium, grails

I am compiling the following dependency:

```
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.48.2'
```

It is returning this specific Jar called `asm-3.1.jar`, which is conflicting with another thing I'm compiling.

How can I exclude this one file from it?

I tried using this solution, but no luck:

```
compile ('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.48.2'){
excludes 'org.objectweb.asm'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that dependency is coming from selenium.  Grails 2.2.2 has an explicit runtime dependency on asm 3.1.

See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2185428f9acdfbafb268534a166aa4ab7ff510d4/grails-core/build.gradle#L49.

Separate from that point, the syntax for excluding dependencies can be found at http://docs.grails.org/2.2.2/guide/conf.html#ivy.

You could use something like this:

```
compile ('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.48.2'){
    exclude 'asm'
}
```

As I said above though, that isn't going to get rid of the `asm` dependency because Grails 2.2.2 itself is pulling that in.